# Trouble importing csv with neo4jimport tool in windows

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

I had success importing few million nodes with neo4jimport tool.

```
input error:expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 item ,but has 0 ([]) neo4j
```

This is the error i have been getting when trying to import new set of csv files . The csv file is in utf-8 and i have removed extraneous characters using hexeditor as well.

Import statement is

`Neo4jImport --into  C:\Users\geralt\Desktop\db_1.db --nodes:Visit C:\Users\geralt\Desktop\db\visit.csv`

The first two lines of csv are

```
visit_id:ID(Visit),age,Hospital,ID,UnitId,Date,DeptName
1,42,Hospital,67,2,2004-07-16 00:00:00,Casualty
```

Comment: Perhaps a newline issue?

Comment: Last time i had used the command was on linux with a ';' at the end. This time i was trying it on windows, looks like there shouldn't be a ';' . That solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the `(Visit)` from the header?

```
visit_id:ID,age,Hospital,ID,UnitId,Date,DeptName
1,42,Hospital,67,2,2004-07-16 00:00:00,Casualty
```